# Return empty instead of null

Tags: java, exception, null

I have method search for exceptions

```
ValidationException(String operation) {
    super("Not valid for operation " + checkOperation(operation));
}
```

And method for checking operation

```
private static String checkOperation(String operation) {
    if (operation != null)
        return operation;
    else
        return null;
}
```

If first method start working and `operation == null` we have message  "Not valid for operation null". But it must be "Not valid for operation". What need write instead of `return null`?

Comment: How about `return "";`

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `return operation != null ? operation : "";` Or using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)`: `return Optional.ofNullable(operation).orElse("");`

Comment: and here two more (Java 9) `Objects.toString(operation, "")` or, even better, `Objects.requireNonNullElse(operation, "")`  [no need to write a method (just) for that] {despite the message that operation is `null` isn't  that bad either}

Comment: Why not `super("Not valid for operation " + String.valueOf(operation));` (which will actually tell you `null`  - which is more helpful than an empty string), instead of `super("Not valid for operation " + checkOperation(operation));` Better still it should have failed earlier with an `IllegalArgumentException` or not failed with defensive checking.

Answer (score 5):

Put the space into the return value of `checkOperation`:

```
if (operation != null)
    return " " + operation;
else
    return "";
```

Then invoke like:

```
super("Not valid for operation" + checkOperation(operation));
                           // ^ remove the space here
```

Although I would consider it better to provide two overloads of the constructor:

- one which takes no operation (and constructs the message `Not valid for operation`);
- the other takes an operation (and constructs the message `Not valid for operation whatever`).